# What is the correct term for a set of options?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Note that I am not talking about a set of choices, but options.

To expatiate more, I mean to say: That there set(or group/class etc) that contains subsets that have therein options, where a choice must be made, and when all the subsets of options have been decided upon, the result is a set of choices.

It's best that I provide a general, visual example:

```
Breakfast_choice:[apple, cereal, whatever]; Lunch_choice:[Fish, Sandwich, whatever];
Dinner_choice:[Rice, Curry, unicorns]
```

Say I chose for breakfast, lunch, and dinner: Apple, Fish, and unicorns respectively. Thus my choices are: [Apple, Fish, unicorns]

So, what I basically want is a name for a group of choices. Of course, I could just call them 'choices' but then if I did that there's no way to distinguish between the choices groups as breakfast, lunch, and dinner, i.e they'd 'spill' into eachother.

I also may call them the 'set of choices', but I don't want to sound as if it's a set of choices that have already been made, which is why am hesitant in using the word.

Comment: The best I can do is point out "dip" as used in sampling and statistics. It is still a pretty loose term as far as useage goes.

Comment: Can you clarify this bit - "So, what I basically want is a name for such a group of choices, such as the one you make for breakfast." It would help a lot if you had terminology to present for the other types of subsets you want to look at such as Table of options = everything, Row of options = Breakfast options, Choice = any single choice, Dip = set of choices formed in one action.

Comment: I think some words you have available are: selections, choices, options.  Each of these words can be used to express what is on offer as well as what has been selected.  You just need to choose which words you want to use for each (explain your choice up front if required) and then be consistent.   But I might choose “options” for what’s offered and “choices” or “selections” for what has been selected.

Comment: How about a sequence or series of choices? Or subsequent choices. This prevents the range or set of choices interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking is simply *selections*.

For breakfact, you choose "apple" from the available options. For lunch you choose  "fish" from the available options. For dinner, you choose "unicorns" from the available options. Each of these -- apple, fish, unicorns -- is a selection, and together they are *selections*.

Comment on aparente001's answer: I wouldn't call the three selections "a selection". You could call the three selections a "set of selections" or an "array of selections" -- both would be perfectly fine -- but they don't meet your request for a single word. *Selections* does.

Comment: That pretty much hits the nail of the head. One could say 'please choose an item', or 'please select an item' to mean the same thing, but not 'these are your selections', to mean the same as  'these are your choices', so 'selections' serves the purpose very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically talking about food, and not just using it for an example, then try "meal plan".

If you are looking for the computer science term, then you probably want

[Tuple](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tuple)

> set of (so many) elements —usually used of sets with ordered elements

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, I just mean anything in general.

Answer (score 0):

You want to choose one from Column A, one from Column B, and one from Column C.  That is the popular culture way of explaining this.

Once the *respective choices* have been made, you are looking at a *selection* or an *array of selections*.